# How to return all nodes, properties and property values in a graph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to do this in Java API. For each node, I want to return it's labels, properties, and the property values.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [labels()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-labels), [keys()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) and [reduce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) functions:

```
match(n)
return
    labels(n) as labels,
    keys(n) as properties,
    reduce(accumulator = [], key IN keys(n) | accumulator + n[key]) as values
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Java API, you can use the following methods on a `Node` instance:

- To get just the property keys (without their values): [PropertyContainer.getPropertyKeys()](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getPropertyKeys--)
- To get a Map of all property keys to their values: [PropertyContainer.getAllProperties()](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getAllProperties--)
- To get all labels for the node: [Node.getLabels()](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getLabels--).